# Why doesn't `[<-` work to reorder data frame columns?

Tags: r

Why doesn't this work?

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:2, y = 3:4, z = 5:6)
df[] <- df[c("z", "y", "x")]
df
#>   x y z
#> 1 5 3 1
#> 2 6 4 2
```

notice that the names are in the original order, but the data itself has changed order.

This works just fine

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:2, y = 3:4, z = 5:6)
df[c("z", "y", "x")]
#>   z y x
#> 1 5 3 1
#> 2 6 4 2
```

Comment: It actually did work. You asked R to replace the values not the names

Comment: You can use ``debugonce(`[<-.data.frame`);df[] <- df[c("z", "y", "x")]`` to see what is happening. You can then step through your code in the debugger.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When an extraction is completed the values in the index are replaced not the names. For example, replacing the first item below does not affect the name of the element:

```
x <- c(a=1, b=2)
x[1] <- 3
x
a b 
3 2
```

In your data frame you replaced the values in the same way. The values changed but the names stayed constant. To reorder the data frame avoid the extraction framework.

```
df <- df[c("z", "y", "x")]
```

Comment: Similarly, and for more direct confirmation that only values get replaced, try `df <- data.frame(a=2, b=3); dd <- data.frame(AA=4, BB=5); df[] <- dd; df` .

Answer (score 0):

Just don't put the [] after the df and it will do as you want...

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:2, y = 3:4, z = 5:6)
df <- df[c("z", "y", "x")]
df
#  z y x
#1 5 3 1
#2 6 4 2
```

And if you question is about why, Pierre Lafortune's comment is right.

as a side note, I also like to add the commat to separate dimension:

```
df <- df[,c("z", "y", "x")]
```

I find it more proper.